# changing a looped ceiling rose (LCR) light for a light that only has 3 connections, Live, Neutral and Earth

Tags: lighting

I'm changing a looped ceiling rose (LCR) light for a light that only has 3 connections, Live, Neutral and Earth.

The looped ceiling rose has 3 different metal parts that the wires go into, like this:

[image: http://www.flameport.com/electric/lighting_circuits/ceiling_rose_newcolours.png]

I want to put a flush light up and wandering if its safe to put the terminal block up through the hole in ceiling or do I have to get junction box

Answer (score 1):

In my country a junction box of applicable protection class (=IP code) is mandatory ... terminal blocks are never allowed to lay blank.